# How to remove multiple expressions from a String in java

Tags: java, string

I have to remove Salutations like "C/O, C/o,c/o,S/O,S/o,s/o" etc from a string.These salutations comes a third party service. The service can return anything form these. How to do this effectively. I am doing this by using below code:

```
if(name.contains("C/O")){
            name = name.replace("C/O", "").trim();
            System.out.println("name: "+name);
        }else if(name.contains("S/O")){
            name = name.replace("S/O", "").trim();
            System.out.println("name: "+name);
        }else if(name.contains("c/o")){
            name = name.replace("c/o", "").trim();
            System.out.println("name: "+name);
        }else if(name.contains("S/o")){
            name = name.replace("S/o", "").trim();
            System.out.println("name: "+name);
        }
```

Any better approach to do this. Please suggest.

Comment: You should probably store all possible salutations in an array and loop through them, instead of having multiple if/else statements.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I can get any number of salutations and in any format like "D/O , d/o, D/o,W/o,H/O" etc. Should I put these many if blocks

Comment: you can try using regular expression in [String.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: In every case you basically do the same. Instead you may use **regex** and a single call to something like `replaceAll("(?i)(C/O|S/O)", "")`. The expression removes everything which is `C/O` or `S/O`, case **insensitive**. Then your code is only `name = name.replaceAll("(?i)(C/O|S/O)", "");` and that's it.

Comment: You don't really need to check if `name.contains(some_string)` before performing the substitution `name.replace(some_string, "")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say hello to regex!

```
name = name.replaceAll("(?i)[cs]/o\\s*", "");
```

The regex breakdown:

- `(?i)` means *ignore case*
- `[cs]` means *"c" or "s"*
- `\\s*` means *all white space following (if any)*

Answer (score 1):

A traditional way to do this could look as follows:

```
String[] salutations = {"C/O", "S/O", "c/o", "S/o"};
for (String salutation : salutations)
{
    name = name.replace(salutation, "").trim();
}
```